# Most reliable way to send new data from server to activities in Android?

Tags: android

What is the best way to send data that I receive from a socket connection to all my activities? After research I've come up with the one way to do this but it is not 100% reliable.

**Idea:** Using a service to send local broadcasts and have each activity capture the intents with a broadcast receiver.

**Problem:** I found out that it is recommended or required to register broadcast receivers onResume() and unregister them onPause(). This means that my activities could miss valuable data when they are paused.

**Complicated Solution:** If I have to do it this way then I would have to store all the data my service receives into an android sql database and then each time an activity calls onResumes() it will query the database. However this sound more complicated than I think it should.

**Give me simple solution:** I am wondering how to do this 100% reliable without making it unnecessarily complex.

Comment: why not put it in a data structure that meets your needs? You can access those from any activity

Comment: Adding to what Marcin said, there is an Application class that you can use to store data that's accessible from any activity at any time. You could pull the data from the server, parse it, and store it in a data structure object in the Application class. Then just query the Application class from any activities that need the data.

Comment: You to store all the data from the server in my own data structure and then copy that data structure when an activity calls onResume()?

Comment: Objects in java are passed by reference and not value. You can use dependency injection to pass the structure to  your activity. No need to copy anything. or simply have a getData() method that will return the reference to the structure.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with registering/unregistering broadcast receivers in onCreate()/onDestroy()?

Comment: ci_ I've read that onDestroy() is not always called. The Android Docs also have a note here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html saying you won't receieve intents when onPause() is called.